# TypeError: on_ready() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'ctx' and 'message'

Tags: python, nextcord

when trying to run my discord bot i get an error in my code for this command, it says that i do not have 'ctx' and 'message' even though its in line 2 of the code

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready(ctx, message):
# if streamer is streaming then ping the role)
if twitchAPI.is_streaming(streamervar) and channelidvar != None:
    await ctx.send(f'{streamervar} is streaming')
    await channelidvar.send(f'@{rolevar} {streamervar} is streaming!')
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
elif twitchAPI.is_streaming(streamervar) and rolevar==None:
    await ctx.send(f'@everyone {streamervar} is streaming')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a command, it is an event that takes no arguments and only runs once when the bot comes online. If you want to make this into a command you should do:

```
@bot.command()
async def notify(ctx): # removed message argument since it wasn't used in the snippet
  # if streamer is streaming then ping the role)
  if twitchAPI.is_streaming(streamervar) and channelidvar != None:
      await ctx.send(f'{streamervar} is streaming')
      await bot.get_channel(channelidvar).send(f'@{rolevar} {streamervar} is streaming!')
      await bot.wait_until_ready()
  elif twitchAPI.is_streaming(streamervar) and rolevar==None:
      await ctx.send(f'@everyone {streamervar} is streaming')
```

If you want to it to run `on_ready`, you should remove the arguments and specify the channel since you can't use 'context' in an event, like so:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  # if streamer is streaming then ping the role)
  if twitchAPI.is_streaming(streamervar) and channelidvar != None:
      await bot.get_channel(channel_id).send(f'{streamervar} is streaming')
      await bot.get_channel(channelidvar).send(f'@{rolevar} {streamervar} is streaming!')
  elif twitchAPI.is_streaming(streamervar) and rolevar==None:
      await bot.get_channel(channel_id).send(f'@everyone {streamervar} is streaming')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not referring to your function definition, but rather where `on_ready` is being called. Somewhere it is being called with no arguments, but you have specified it should take *two*.

See the API documentation for [`on_ready`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.on_ready), where it is shown with zero arguments.